# Prevent keyup linebreak

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to prevent additional line breaks in my textarea. I use the below within my keyup function to prevent this.

```
$('textarea#tt').val($('textarea#tt').val().replace(/^(\r\n)|(\n\n)/,''));
```

But if the user holds the enter key it doesn't work as expected. How can I fix this? Example

prevent

```
The brown
          //additional line space
kettle
          //additional line space
          //additional line space
```

Expected

```
The brown
kettle
```

Comment: Your `regex` replaces only first occurrences, and replaces `\r\n` only when it occurs at the start of the input, not anywhere else, while for double `\n\n` you do not check for the `\r\n\r\n` kind. Is this all intended? What if the user copy/pastes text in the input with many such breaks?

Comment: I updated my answer by assuming you want all double line breaks replaced by single line breaks, and that any initial line break should be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to treat the `keypress` event in the same way, and you could even add the `keydown` event as well:

```
$('textarea#tt').bind('keypress keyup keydown', function (e) {
    $(this).val($(this).val().
        replace(/^(\n|\r\n)+/, '').
        replace(/(\n|\r\n){2,}/g, '\n'));
});
```

Note that I have also modified the `regex`:

- it treats line-breaks equally whether they are `\n` or `\r\n`;
- it replaces double (triple, ...) line-breaks with a single one;
- using the `g` modifier it replaces all occurrences. This is needed for instances where the user pastes a long text into the `textarea` with potentially many double line-breaks;
- any number of initial line-breaks are removed.